# OS X compressed files on a Windows machine

Tags: windows, macos, compression, archiving

I sent myself a compressed folder from my OS X machine to my Windows machine. When I opened it I of course got the __MACOSX folder, but the contents were in an extension-less file of about the right number of bits.

How can I look at this on a Windows box?

Comment: Remember that some files on Mac OS X store their actual content in the resource fork that is compressed to the `__MACOSX` folder. What file types are in that folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That folder is a mac generated folder, you ignore that on Windows, the actual files that you placed in the archive will be in the same location.

So you would have:

```
_MACOSX
file1
file2
```

You may not have compressed the files correctly, go back and try again.